# Passing Multiple Parameters to ASP.NET Web API With jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

POST form variables to simple parameters of a Web API method in ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/products',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { Id: 2012, Name: 'test', Category: 'My Category', Price: 99.5 },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

but its not working how to do this?

Comment: I do exactly what you've used above, but use .ashx files to handle calls and use `Context.Request.Form[]` to get the post data.  It has the advantage that ashx files are nice and fast.

Comment: @Archer i have used the answer below ... is that answer  worthy to use  ?

Comment: If it works for you then yes.  I tried various methods of handling .Net calls from Javascript and ended up doing the above.  I was just letting you know about it as I find it simple, albeit a bit "old school".

Comment: Can you post your `ApiController`?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code it will work. Only change I have made is in `data` parameter where I am doing `JSON.stringify()`, faced with same issue quite a few months back. Basically it expects a string which can be parsed to `JSON`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/products',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Id: 2012, Name: 'test', Category: 'My Category', Price: 99.5 }),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```